# how to perform transpose of join result

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpXOC.png)Below attached ss are the sample data of my join query, now I want to achieve transpose of this data as id, last updated, provider reference, building reference as my column names, and Val column as my data for the respective headers. The Query I'm using to do join is as below. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

**Join:**

```sql
select lc.id, lc.name,lc.type, sl.val 
       from Lease_col_str lc inner join SEP_LEASE_STR sl
       on lc.id=sl.COLUMNID;
```

[This is the result of join query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5tPP.png)

[image]

[Desired output after join query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AY9a.png)

[image]

Comment: please share your original query, and exactly how you want the end results to look

Comment: I have added the ss for the desired output, Please on the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, the below query helped me to achieve this.

```
    select * from
(select  lc.name, sl.val 
       from Lease_col_str lc inner join
       SEP_LEASE_STR sl on lc.id=sl.COLUMNID) t
       pivot (max(val) 
              for name 
              in ('Last Updated','Provider Reference','Building Reference')) as p ;
```